# Can not browse 2 mfp console at the same browser

Tags: session, ibm-mobilefirst, instance, websphere-liberty, mfp

Good day,

Previously I have a WebSphere Application Server Liberty Core, and install 1 mfp server inside.
I named this mfp server as `mfp1`, its working fine and I can login to the console correctly.
This is my mfp console endpoint `https://10.8.2.65:9443/mfpconsole/login.html`

Today I install another mfp into same Liberty Core, I named it as `mfp2` and configure it as different port. The installation process working fine, and I can browse the console with following endpoint:
`https://10.8.2.65:9444/mfpconsole/login.html`

However, after done install, I found there are some issues. I can not browse 2 mfp console in the same browser. The simulation steps are as follow:

1. when I first open my chrome, and I browse to first mfp console,  `https://10.8.2.65:9443/mfpconsole/login.html`, the page display correctly,
2. Then I open another new tab, and I browse to second mfp console, `https://10.8.2.65:9444/mfpconsole/login.html`, the page display correctly as well.
3. But when I key in user name and password in second tab and click login, it will auto jump to first mfp endpoint login page.

Furthermore, I can not login to both mfp console at same browser. The simulation steps are as follow:

1. when I first open my chrome, and I browse to first mfp console,  `https://10.8.2.65:9443/mfpconsole/login.html`, the page display correctly.
2. I key in user name and password, click Login, it will login successfully.
3. Then I open another new tab, and I browse to second mfp console, `https://10.8.2.65:9444/mfpconsole/login.html`, the page display correctly as well.
4. However, when I come back to my first tab, which is the first mfp console, it will auto logout.

I believe there are some configuration I have to do to fix this. Can anyone advice on this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is normal, because session cookies are based on a hostname not port. So I'd suggest you either to use 2 different browsers, or edit your etc/hosts file and add 2 diff host aliases there like mfp1 and mfp2 and use these aliasses to access consoles.

Comment: I saw Jboss EAP server can handle different session with same ip and different port. From example, in my jboss server, I can create many EAP, each of them different IP, and I can access them in same browser correctly. Is it anything I can do the same configuration at MFP in liberty core?

Comment: You could rename default jsessionid cookies for different servers, but I'd say that adding hostname to etc is much easier and straight forward.